# Making a Website without using frameworks

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it okay if you're only knowlegable in html,css,js,sql,php for making a website but don't botther to learn frameworks like bootstrap...If no what are the advantage when using frameworks

Comment: The things you mentioned is what makes most web sites tick so that's enough. Using frameworks makes it easy you don't have code each and every function it's there in the framework you only have learn how to call that function and use it in your site. Ex: pagination if you use `bootstarp` it\s already there you just need to call it in and tell it how to work. **Also this question might get down votes better delete it**.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it will be okay, according to this [articles](http://www.vizteams.com/blog/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-frameworks/), frameworks has some advantages

> **EFFICIENCY**
>
> Jobs that generally would take you hours and hundreds of lines of code
>   to compose, can now be done in minutes with pre-built functions.
>   Development becomes a lot easier, so if it’s much easier it’s quicker,
>   and subsequently effective.
>
> **SECURITY**
>
> An extensively utilized framework has big security applications. The
>   big benefit is the neighborhood behind it, where users end up being
>   long-lasting testers. If you find a vulnerability or a security hole,
>   you can go to the framework’s web site and let the team understand so
>   they can fix it.
>
> **EXPENSE**
>
> Most popular structures are complimentary, and considering
>   that it likewise helps the developer to code faster, the expense for
>   the final client will certainly be smaller.
>
> **SUPPORT**
>
> distributed tool, a framework generally includes documents, a support
>   group, or huge community online forums where you can acquire quick
>   responsesAs any other